# 400 errors while making a scrapy post request with headers and payload

Tags: python, scrapy, http-post

I'm making a spider to scrape a list of games from Nintendo.
I've checked the request format with postman and with the python requests library and I get the results I need. However, when I create the request with scrapy I'm getting 400 errors.

Here's the spider:

```
class NintendoSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "nintendo"

    def start_requests(self):
        url = 'https://u3b6gr4ua3-dsn.algolia.net/1/indexes/*/queries'

        headers = {}
        headers['x-algolia-api-key'] = 'a29c6927638bfd8cee23993e51e721c9'
        headers['x-algolia-application-id'] = 'U3B6GR4UA3'

        formdata = {
            "requests":[
                {
                    "indexName":"store_game_en_us",
                    "params":'&hitsPerPage=40&maxValuesPerFacet=20&page=0'
                }
            ]
        }

        yield scrapy.Request( url, method='POST', headers=headers, body=json.dumps(formdata), callback=self.parse)

    def parse(self, response):
        print(response)
```

Comment: Please include the errors you are receiving

Comment: can you try this .  yield scrapy.Request( url, method='POST', headers=headers, body=json.dumps(formdata), self.parse)

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code and it is working fine. Which means you were rate limited/banned.

Try again and see the `response.json()` in `parse` method. If it works, it was a temporary ban.

From now on, you need to slow down the scraping or use proxies.

Use `DOWNLOAD_DELAY` and `AUTOTHROTTLE_ENABLED` settings. See the [documentation](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/practices.html#avoiding-getting-banned) on this topic.